# How to convert Date format to SimpleDateFormat on android?

Tags: android

recently I get String `"23:00"` .

I know convert string to Date

```
private String strtime;
private Date datetime;
SimpleDateFormat simtime = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");

datatime = simtime.parse(strtime);
```

datetime is --> `Thu Jan 01 23:00:00 GMT+09:00 1970

but I want only get `23:00`

how to use convert date to simpledateformat?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26971028/7320259 check this hope it helps

Comment: What will you do with it? You got `23:00` then you parse via SDF then you get again `23:00`?

Comment: @TruongHieu   compare `23:00` to `current time` so , I want only get `23:00`

Comment: Ok. I'll write my answer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer below may not help people but can help @hyunwookcho somehow.

I think you want to compare that `HH:mm` to `current time`. So I recommend you to change to other way: Compare that `String` with `current HH:mm`.

```
private String strtime = "23:00";
private String currentHours = "";
SimpleDateFormat simtime = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
currentHours = simtime.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
if (strtime.equals(currentHours)){
//same hours
}else{
//diff hours
}
```

**UPDATE**
If you want to compare between 2 points of time. I suggest you use this

```
String strtime1 = "23:00";
String strtime2 = "17:00";
String currentHours = "";
String[] strs_time1 = strtime1.split(":");
String[] strs_time2 = strtime2.split(":");

Calendar c_time1 = Calendar.getInstance();
c_time1.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.parseInt(strs_time1[0]));
c_time1.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(strs_time1[1]));

Calendar c_time2 = Calendar.getInstance();
c_time2.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.parseInt(strs_time2[0]));
c_time2.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(strs_time2[1]));

Calendar currentCal = Calendar.getInstance();

if (currentCal.getTimeInMillis() >= c_time2.getTimeInMillis() && currentCal.getTimeInMillis() <= c_time1.getTimeInMillis()){
    // FIRE IN THE HOLE
}
```

Comment: thanks, More detail, I have 2 time `17:00` and `23:00`     , when I app booting, if the current time is between `17:00` and `23:00` , `A` method execute.

Comment: So you have to substring by hand and set it into `Calendar.getInstance()`. I'll update my code.

Comment: thanks, and I have question.   `17:00` and `23:00` is String. (not Date format) , current time is dataformat.    compare string to date is possible ?

Comment: @hyunwookcho i updated my code. My answer is **NO**. Easy reason is they are not same types. You have convert current time to `String` then compare `String` with `String`.

Comment: ah, sorry.Between `17:00` and `23:00`

Comment: Glad to help you @hyunwookcho

Comment: oh, sorry I have 1 question. how to set `04:00` time ? tomorrow time.    how to set tomorrow time use `getTimeInMillis?`

Comment: `calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);`  or add `24*60*60*1000` milliseconds to get next day.

Comment: @hyunwookcho to set "04:00" time, you can use `c_time1.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.parseInt("04"));`
`c_time1.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt("00"));`

Comment: `calendar.add(Calender.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1)` is not answer. this is `Feb 01` day

Comment: @hyunwookcho did you even test it? I use `add` not `set`. And I am very sure that my code works.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static final String TimeFormate = "hh:mm a";
    public static String getCurrentDateTime() {
    SimpleDateFormat from = new SimpleDateFormat(TimeFormate);
    from.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
    String current = from.format(new Date());
    return current;
}
```

it will help you for sure, It will provide you your perspective time format

Comment: thanks, but `current` is String. I want Date format `"23:00"`